# Behavior of GHCI :sprint command

Tags: haskell

In the tutorial [What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/) there is this interaction inside GHCi regarding the use of the `:sprint` command to inspect the state of evaluation of some variable:

```
λ: let a = [1..] :: [Integer]
λ: :sprint a
a = _
λ: a !! 4
5
λ: :sprint a
a = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : _
```

However, if we ommit the part `:: [Integer]` from the definition of `a`, the last call to `:sprint a` will return `a = _` and not `a = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : _`.

Why?

*ANSWER*: the monomorphism restriction must be turned on/off inside GHCi via `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` and `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` (see Reid Barton's comment below). And the best explanation I found for `:sprint` behavior is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2j56e0/sprint_behaves_differently_in_ghc_783/).

Comment: If you are using 7.10.2 then the monomorphism restriction is turned off by default, so the type of `[1..]` (without `:: Integer`) is polymorphic and thus the referred to answer applies.

Comment: @user5402 I am using GHCi 7.8.3, and even if I launch it with `ghci -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` or `ghci -XMonomorphismRestriction` I still have the same problem. I suppose that `:sprint` should have been implemented to make this subtlety transparent for the user.

Comment: Apparently `ghci -XMonomorphismRestriction` doesn't turn on the monomorphism restriction. You need to `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` from inside ghci. Confusing...

Comment: @ReidBarton Thanks, it worked. I don't understand why this monomorphism restriction is still around generating lots of confusion. Anyway, with or without such restriction, the problem is that GHCi has inconsistencies regarding `:sprint` (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3dznm2/question_about_the_behavoir_of_sprint_in_ghci/)).